# Unexpected output of int datatype

Tags: c

I created a simple program from the book let us c pg no.26 which is an example to illustrate and the code is somewhat like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char x,y;
int z;
x = 'a';
y = 'b';
z = x + y;
printf("%d", z);

return 0;
}
```

But the output i expected was the string ab (i know the z is in int but still that was the output i can think of) but instead the output was 195 which shocked me so please help me to figure this out in easy words.

Comment: C just works like that. Read "The C Programming Language", it's a classic book.

Comment: `%d` prints a number in decimal, never letters/a string.

Comment: But why the output was only 195

Comment: Because a is char 97 and b is char 98. Get used to the ASCII table too.

Comment: @uprego thanks a very big thanks this is the first time answer is solved otherwise most of the times either the mod take down my answer or some answer that I can't understand your comment motivates me that there is still hope :) again thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chars/letters are internally represented as numbers in terms of some protocols (e.g., Ascii or Unicode). ASCII is a popular standard to represent the most common symbols and letters. Here is the ASCII table. This table tells all the common symbols/letters in [ASCII](http://plato.asu.edu/MAT420/beginning_perl/3145_AppF.pdf) are essentially a number between 0 and 255 (ASCII has two parts: 0 to 127 is the standard ASCII; the upper range of 128 to 255 is defined in Extended ASCII; many variants of extended ASCII are used).

[image]

To put it into the context of your code, here is what happened.

```
// The letter/char 'a' is internally saved as 97 in the memory
// The letter/char 'b' is internally saved as 98 in the memory
x = 'a'; // this will copy 97 to x
y = 'b'; // this will copy 98 to x
z = x +y ; // 97+98=195 -> z
```

If you want to print "ab", you must have two chars next to each other. Here is what you should do

```
char z[3];
z[0]='a'; //move 'a' or 97 to the first element of z (recall in C, the index is zero-based
z[1]='b';//move 'b' or 98 to the second element or z
z[2]=0;  //In C, a string is null-ended. That is, the last element must be a null (i.e.,0).

print("%s\n",z); // you will get "ab"
```

Alternatively, you can get "ab" in the following way based on the Ascii table:

```
char z[3];
z[0]=97; //move 97 to the first element of z, which is 'a' based on the ascii table
z[1]=98;//move 98 to the second element or z, which is 'b'
z[2]=0;  //In C, a string is null-ended. That is, the last element must be a null (i.e.,0).

print("%s\n",z); // you will get "ab"
```

**Edit/comment:**

Considering this comment:

> "Chars are signed on x86, so the range is -128 ... 127 and not 0 ... 255 as you state ".

Note that nowhere did I mention that the char type in C has a range of 0 ... 255. I refer to [0 ... 255 ] only in the context of the ASCII standard.

Comment: Chars are signed on x86, so the range is -128 ... 127 and not 0 ... 255 as you state

Comment: Whether characters are encoded with ASCII is implementation-defined. Do not assert it unconditionally as a feature of C; that teaches people incorrectly.

Comment: ASCII standard was 7 bits i.e. 0...127

Answer (score 1):

You summed up 97 to 98, hence the 195.

Feeding a sum of two `char` in an `int` will promote those `char` to `int` then store the result.

Then if you want that to be printed as a string, you can `printf("%s\n", z);`. Printing `%d` will interpret the variable as a decimal signed integer.

<sub>Don't print that as a string, because you don't know how far the first chars array terminator is.</sub>

<sub><sub>Chars array in C, for many functions such as `printf`, don't end *where its size ends*, but where the terminator char (`0x00` or `0` or `'\0'`) marks its end.</sub></sub>